# Issue with Neodash Bar Graph Legend Color

Tags: neo4j, bar-chart, visualization, jqbargraph

I am using Neodash to build a Bar graph. When viewing the legend, a lot of the entries are shown with black color instead of the actual color that is there is the graph. Anyone can help figure out why and how to fix this? Below is an example image.
[image: Example Image]

Setting for the graph:

```
{
      "title": "#tasks assigned per month per person",
      "query": "match(i:Issue)-[:AssignedTo]-(a:Assignee)\n//WHERE i.type = \"Bug\"\nWHERE a.name <> \"null\"    \nWITH apoc.date.parse(i.createdOn, 'ms', 'dd/MMM/yy h:mm a') AS milliseconds,i,a\nWITH date(datetime({epochmillis: milliseconds})) AS createDate, i, a\nWITH apoc.temporal.format(createDate, \"yyy\") AS Year, apoc.temporal.format(createDate, \"MM\") AS Month,i,a\nWHERE Year >= \"2020\" AND Year < \"2021\"\nRETURN Month, a.name AS AssignedTo,count(i) AS NumReq\nORDER BY Month\n\n\n",
      "width": 6,
      "height": 2,
      "x": 0,
      "y": 12,
      "type": "bar",
      "selection": {
        "index": "Month",
        "value": "NumReq",
        "key": "AssignedTo"
      },
      "settings": {
        "type": "Node Property",
        "barValues": false,
        "legend": true,
        "labelRotation": 0,
        "hideSelections": true,
        "fullscreenEnabled": true,
        "downloadImageEnabled": true,
        "marginBottom": 50,
        "marginLeft": 100,
        "marginRight": 300,
        "showOptionalSelections": true,
        "groupMode": "grouped",
        "colors": "nivo",
        "minValue": 0
      },
      "database": "datadb",
      "id": "542a6250-c3d3-4623-af22-570523160004"
    }
```

Comment: please show us your code or settings so that we can fix it. Thanks.

Comment: @jose_bacoy, added the settings that are applied for this visualization in Neodash.